# DevExpress XtraReports binding subreport datasource to report's datasource of collection

Tags: collections, devexpress, subreport, xtrareport

I'm having some trouble with binding a *DevExpress XtraReport* subreport's datasource to it's containing report's datasource.  The datasource is an object collection.

If I create a basic reports with sub detail sections all is well.

For example, the object collection is a list of companies.  Each company has a list of addresses and a list of contacts.  What I am attempting is to create a report with two subreports side-by-side for each (detail) company.

From several web articles, I thought this approach seemed like it would work:

```
report.ContactSubreport.ReportSource.DataSource = report.Datasource
```

which I call from a script using the subreport's BeforePrint event.

I also tried setting the datamember to the name of the sub collection:

```
report.ContactSubreport.ReportSource.DataMember = "Contacts"
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From what I gather, you need to display only child collections' records that belong to the current master record.

In this case, it's better to handle the BeforePrint event of those XRSubreports and call there the XtraReport.GetCurrentRow method for a master report. This method call will return a master record (i.e., an instance of the "Company" object). This will allow you to pass the "Company.Addresses" list to the first subreport and the "Company.Contacts" list to the second one. Thus, the details that only correspond to each "Company" will be printed in both subreports.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplish XtraSubReport dynamic or runtime data binding by doing Something like this and it WORKS perfectly
(VB.NET but can easily be implemented in C#)

**NOTE**:

1. The BandKind.Detail parameter below means the subreport was placed in the Detail Band. If not then specify the band of the main report where you placed the subreport in (eg. PageHeader, ReportHeader, PageFooter, etc)
2. The "XrSubreportInvoiceBank" is the name of the subReport that you created in the main report. You will need to change it to the name of the subreport in your main report

---

```
Dim MyDocument As New XtraReportInvoiceHardcopy
Dim BankSubreport As XRSubreport = CType(MyDocument.Bands(BandKind.Detail).FindControl("XrSubreportInvoiceBank", True), XRSubreport)

Dim BankAccount As DataTable = New DataTable 'You can put your Data in here
BankSubreport.ReportSource.DataSource = BankAccount 
BankSubreport.Visible = True
```